# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am not able to **initialize Firebase** in my Flutter project I have tried **importing** the `firebase-app.js` ,`firebase-auth.js` and `firebase-analytics.js` but nothing worked I am currently using **`Firebase 9.0.1`**, I am tired of solving this error its not been solved from 1 week and I have tried everything on Stackoverflow and searched the documentation on Firebase and Flutter I have attached screenshot of the error check below which I get when build and run,

Also I have enabled firebase functions in my firebase console so does it needs to be imported to my project as of now I ain't using it but is it mandatory to so?

First time when run `flutter run -d chrome` the **Error Output** is,

[image]

**main.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:devcom/auth.dart';
import 'package:devcom/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:devcom/root_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AuthProvider(
      auth: Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter login demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: RootPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  
    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="devcom">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
  
    <title>Devcom</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  </head>
<body > 
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js" type = "module"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-analytics.js" type="module"> </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-auth.js" type = "module"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-firestore.js" type="module"></script>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first --><script> var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "......",
      databaseURL: ".....",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      measurementId: "",
      appId: "1:.........:web:...........",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); // the error is pointing out this line for the cause 
    firebase.analytics();
</script><script>
var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
var scriptLoaded = false;
function loadMainDartJs() {
  if (scriptLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  scriptLoaded = true;
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
  scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
  document.body.append(scriptTag);
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Service workers are supported. Use them.
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
    // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
    // potentially different versions.
    var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
      .then((reg) => {
        function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
          serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
            if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
              console.log('Installed new service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });
        }
        if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
          // No active web worker and we have installed or are 
          installing
          // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
          waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
        } else if 
        (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
          // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, 
          so we
          // need to ask the service worker to update.
          console.log('New service worker available.');
          reg.update();
          waitForActivation(reg.installing);
        } else {
          // Existing service worker is still good.
          console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
          loadMainDartJs();
        }
      });

    // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
    // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!scriptLoaded) {
        console.warn(
          'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
        );
        loadMainDartJs();
      }
    }, 4000);
  });
} else {
  // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
  loadMainDartJs();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**pubspec.yaml**:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: 
  cupertino_icons: 
  firebase_core: 
  firebase_core_web:
  firebase_auth_web:
    
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito:
```

**Edits suggested for using version 8.7.1:**

it throws me : `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem cause was `Auth` used in **Myapp class** in main.dart it works fine if we remove the `AuthProvider` widget from there and also the version needs to be changed  from 9 to version 8.7.1 as Flutter bindings are built on that and the support for version 9 is yet to come.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change firebase version to 8.7.1

Comment: I have tried using that but my current version of `firebase-tools` is 9.17.0 and the firebase config file from `firebase console` suggest to add 9.0.1 so I tried adding that too but  with all three all of the above didnt worked.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Comment: Firebase V9 has a lot of changes. 
You can read here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade
Basically: V9 has 2 options for you => Modular or Compat.
Your code is using Modular.
Therefore you should change “ firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)” => “initializeApp(firebaseConfig)”

Comment: thanks a lot but can you plz then provide me the proper format like how I should format my `index.html` and `main.dart` file  I gave it try as its mentioned in the documentation you send but its still giving me new errors